# How to access external MS SQL database from Javascript in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, database, google-chrome

I use the code like below to access MS SQL database from Javascript in Internet Explorer -

```js
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var connectionstring = "Data Source=dbname;Initial Catalog=DefaultCatalog;User ID=user;Password=pass;Provider=SQLOLEDB";
```

It doesn't work in Google Chrome. What should I use there?

(I understand that this is unsecure to access DB directly from javascript. And I don't have any access to the server to access data there and realize some API to read data thru this API)

Comment: I would think putting your connection string in a javascript file would be highly frowned upon as it would make it very easy for a hacker to gain access to your Database.

Comment: Did you check for errors in the console? You should definitely use a REST API instead though!

Comment: @EdwinKrause, this is well known that ActiveXObject is not supported by Chrome, the console shows `Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined`, so I am looking for workaround.
I can not use an API, since it is not supported by the server.

Comment: You can't access a database through a browser any way except ActiveX, and that's really intended for local networks and HTAs, not general use on the web, since any user could steal the database credentials and do as they pleased with it. Not to mention it's an old, dead technology. It'd be a massive security hole anyway if you could. If the server doesn't have an API or other server-side code which can respond to HTTP requests, you need to create it, and use that as an intermediary between your JS code and your database. This is what every online application in the world does.